# Why is Azure static web app going over size limit

Tags: azure, github, azure-static-web-app

In my Azure static web app (which has an Azure function folder), I keep trying to build and deploy but it is hitting a size limit for the Standard plan, which allows a max app size of 500mb. I am not even close to that size. Why is the github action failing, and how can I get it to pass?

Here is the error message below:

```
---End of Oryx build logs---
Function Runtime Information. OS: linux, Functions Runtime: ~4, node version: 16
Finished building function app with Oryx
Zipping Api Artifacts
Done Zipping Api Artifacts
The content server has rejected the request with: BadRequest
Reason: The size of the function content was too large. The limit for this Static Web App is 104857600 bytes.
```

Comment: How big is the zipped API Artifacts?   Are you sure you're sending the correct thing?  The error isn't showing what content it is rejecting, so I'm assuming it's the zipped api artifacts...

Comment: @ewokx I'm not sure how big the zipped API Artifacts are. The build and deploy job in GitHub Actions doesn't seem to output that value, it just says that the Artifacts are too large. I'm almost positive that yes, it is rejecting the size of the artifacts because it is the last message printed before the job exits due to error.

Comment: Is it zipping up extraneous stuff?   Is it possible to show the list of files in the zipped archive?

Comment: From what I can tell it's not; I do wish it would output the size, but when I run a build of the react app it's only 368kb. And I doubt the api folder which houses the Azure function is even the same size.

Comment: Could you please share your GitHub Repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being that I needed to reduce the size of my /api folder (created via VScode's Azure Functions 'create HTTP function').

I'm not sure why the size of the folder needs to be so small but it did solve the error and my app was able to build and deploy successfully.